# Improve performance for my VM instance on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cpu-usage, google-compute-engine

We already have a VM instance which is a custom (6 vCPUs, 32 GB memory) Intel Sandy Bridge.
The CPU utilization is always at 60%. Is that normal? Can be improved in order to optimize server response times?

[image]

Also, the server everyday between 3:00AM to 5:00 AM the website goes into maintenance (HTTP 503 status). Can be a problem from the server? o any configuration that is wrong?

Thanks in advance for your attention.
Regards

Comment: if you want someone help you, first you need to tell what kind of sofware you have in your vm, your explanation is so generic.

Comment: Hi, it's a Debian Machine which have installed Magento 1.9.3

Comment: Have you tried using the [Google Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs/) for deploying a software package (Magento) ?. If not, I will highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to run a top or htop command to check the processes that you are running. Maybe you are running something that eats your CPU.